# Is there a way to check nested option values in one pattern in F#?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, pattern-matching, monads

Let's pretend we have the following types:

```
type Message {
    text : Option<string>
}

type Update {
    msg : Option<Message> 
}
```

How do I match it in one line, like in C# using null-conditional operator i.e `update?.msg?.text` ?

Is there a way to do it like this?:

```
match msg, msg.text with 
| Some msg, Some txt -> ...
| None -> ...
```

because I don't want to be writing 2 nested match expressions.

Comment: The `.?` operator in C# is basically `Option.map/bind`, with the difference that F# is more versatile (you're not bound to the object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two Record types (missing the "=" in your example). To match some variable of Update type, you could do as follows:

```
type Message = { text : Option<string> }

type Update = { msg : Option<Message> }

let u = {msg = Some({text = Some "text"})}

//all 3 possible cases
match u with
| {msg = Some({text = Some t})} -> t
| {msg = Some({text = None})} -> ""
| {msg = None} -> ""
```